# postgresql is incrementing an update by 2?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm migrating our model to postgresql for the FTS and data integrity

```
update myschema.counters set counter_count= (counter_count+1) where counter_id =?
```

Works as expected in mysql, however in postgres it is incrementing by 2 each time?  It is simple int field I believe, I don't have anything special going on.

Comment: This is impossible unless you have a `trigger` that is mucking with the update. or a complex `rule`.

Comment: I do not, I'm really at a loss for why this is happening too.  I haven't done anything fancy with the DB yet.  0 triggers or rules.

Comment: You execute the query twice, check the logfile to see both queries.

Comment: Yea, that's what was happening. Noob mistake, using a new library.  Thought I had to do `stmt->execute()` after a `stmt = query()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html) to populate the value.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE counter_seq START 1;

UPDATE myschema.counters 
   SET counter_count = NEXTVAL('counter_seq')
 WHERE counter_id = ?
```